# DataTables: Entries displaying do not work

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm using DataTables **1.19** to paginate and mostly to optimize a table with more than 2000 records.

Everything works fine, the only issue is that DataTables says: "Showing 1 to 10 of 2,001 entries"

When is actually showing more than 500 per page, here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW2Ww.jpg).

Code:

**Jquery DataTables:**

```
    url = location.search;

                        var table = $('.data-table').dataTable({
                            "bJQueryUI": true,
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                            "sDom": '<""lri>t<"F"fp>',
                            "aaSorting": [],
                            "bServerSide": true,
                            "bProcessing": true,
                            "sAjaxSource": "/ledger/ajax"+url,
                            "fnServerParams": function(aoData) {
                            },
                            "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
//                                console.log(nRow);
//                                console.log(aData);
                                $('td:eq(1)', nRow).css('text-align', 'right');
                                $('td:eq(2)', nRow).css('text-align', 'right');
                                $('td:eq(3)', nRow).css('text-align', 'right');
                                $('td:eq(4)', nRow).css('text-align', 'right');
                                $('td:eq(5)', nRow).css('text-align', 'right');
                                $('td:eq(6)', nRow).css('text-align', 'right');

                            },
                            "oLanguage": {
                                "sUrl": "/js/language/" + js_lang + ".txt"
                            },
                            "bStateSave": true
                        });
```

[Here](https://prnt.sc/gnxh5v) is a brief preview of the AJAX Response.

I Appreciate every comment. Thanks!

Comment: You have enabled bServerSide: true. So, maybe your serverside returns wrong numbers for iTotalRecords and iTotalDisplayRecords.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the page length?

```
"iDisplayLength": 50
```

I know the default value is supposed to be 10, but give it a try...

And I see that you're using server side processing... Maybe tthe answer of the php file has some error in its format. Paste the answer if you can (not all rows needed, just the beginning and the end).

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it. The issue was that in order to create the AJAX Query with the data, I created a collection of the data instead of a query directly from the database (I did not use Datatable::query($data)) So my AJAX response syntax was wrong.

I had to do this to fix the structure of the AJAX response:

```
public function getAjax()
    {
        $inputs = Input::only(['period','date_start', 'date_end', 'grupoContable']);
        $inputs = array_filter($inputs);

        $results = $this->calculateAsientos($inputs);

        $collection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

        foreach($results as $result) {
            $collection->add($result);
        }


        return Datatable::collection($collection)
            ->showColumns(  'fecha', 'comentarios', 'line_cargo', 'line_abono', 'nombreCuentaContable', 'cuentaContable')
            ->searchColumns(  'fecha', 'comentarios', 'line_cargo', 'line_abono', 'nombreCuentaContable', 'cuentaContable')
            ->orderColumns(  'fecha', 'cuentaContable', 'nombreCuentaContable', 'comentarios', 'line_cargo', 'line_abono')
            ->make();
    }
```